# For loop copying files in subfolders that contain hyphens

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am testing out writing a batch file to move specific files, and have come across it's distaste for "-" as an invalid parameter.

Code I am using in the .bat:

```
set source="E:\Source"
for /r %source% %%a in (*1234*abcd*.txt) do robocopy %%~dpsa E:\Destination *1234*abcd*.txt
```

The subfolders contained in E:\Source will have hyphens in the folder names, and therefore this returns an error for "-" as an invalid parameter. It shows the source filepath as stopping at the hyphen ("E:\Source\July")... is there a way around this?

Comment: In my expert opinion, hyphens are not a special character and should not cause any problems.  Now if your file paths have other special characters or spaces in them, then you need to quote your file paths.  Regardless it is always a best practice to quote all file paths and/or file names.  Sounds like it is a bug in Robocopy.

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a `FOR /R` with Robocopy.  You don't need to.  Robocopy can span directory trees.